# How to access column name by the value stored in that column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table its name is 'specialization' database name is 'hackathon' inside table it have one row and 8 columns "id" "name" "soft_dev" "Data_analytics" "DB_manager" "sys_engineer" "research" "networks_admin" the first row data is "5 , gourav, 59.7 ,72.6,73.87,59.14,43.14,50.74" these are values respectively now.I am on $row['Data_analytics'] means I can access value 72.6 now I want to find out the name of this column in which it is stored Like the name is "Data_analytics". I want this value to be return how we can do it

```
<?php
$value = 72.6; // the value you have access to
// Connect to the database
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hackathon");
// Prepare the query
$query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'specialization' AND table_schema = 'hackathon' 
AND (column_name LIKE 'soft_dev' OR column_name LIKE 'Data_analytics' OR column_name LIKE 'DB_manager' OR column_name LIKE 'sys_engineer' OR column_name LIKE 'research' OR column_name LIKE 'networks_admin') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM specialization WHERE Data_analytics = ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("d", $value);
$stmt->execute();
// Retrieve the result
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
// Get the column name
$column_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
echo "The value " . $value . " is stored in the column " . $column_name;
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

Its giving error saying trying to access null variable or null value when i print column name

Comment: Please include code you have tried so far.

Comment: I am trying to access $row['COLUMN_NAME']

Comment: Yah I know I want it written data_analytics for some reason its just example if I am using some other value then its column should be written

Comment: Does $result have anything in it? Test that it's not empty before trying to read from it. (But your SQL is broken anyway.)

Comment: I am noob I don't have much idea I just want to implement this plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if the result set is empty, or even if it has multiple rows.

Use this pattern in general...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $column_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    echo "The value " . $value . " is stored in the column " . $column_name;
}
```

Or...

```
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
    echo 'No results';
} else {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $column_name = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
        echo "The value " . $value . " is stored in the column " . $column_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: saying no result

Comment: @GouravJangid Because your SQL is returning no results. Like I said, your SQL is broken, but your question was about the php error message. Test your SQL directly on the database, only when it's working should you paste it in to your php. (Feel free to open another question about the SQL.)

Comment: so now what should i do

Comment: @GouravJangid Questions here need to be focused. I answered the php error for you. If you have a SQL question, ask a SQL question... (Don't clutter it with the PHP code, just focus on the SQL query you're struggling with.)